# MySQL query to search multiple keywords in one column

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table that contains a column called `fullName` and it contains these two names:

| fullName |
| --- |
| Peter Andrew Thompson |
| Peter Alan Thompson Jackson |

Now let's say I have a search form and when the user types in `Peter Thompson`, I want both rows to be returned because they both contain the words `Peter` and `Thompson`, even though the middle name is different and the second row has an additional last name in it.

How would the query look like?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'fullName' LIKE '%query%'` did not work.

Comment: is peter thompson allan also required? or alan thompson peter ? etc... Or does the first token have to be peter and thompson can appear anywhere in the rest of the string?

Comment: `WHERE FullName LIKE '%Peter%' AND FullName LIKE '%Thompson%'`

Comment: Or if they have to be in the original order, `WHERE fullName LIKE '%Peter%Thompson%'`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest learning about [fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) features of MySQL.

Here's a demonstration:

```
mysql> create table t ( fullname text, fulltext index (fullname));

mysql> insert into t values ('Peter Andrew Thompson'), ('Peter Alan Thompson Jackson');

mysql> select * from t where match(fullname) against ('+peter +thompson' in boolean mode);
+-----------------------------+
| fullname                    |
+-----------------------------+
| Peter Andrew Thompson       |
| Peter Alan Thompson Jackson |
+-----------------------------+
```